# How to print a specific line/row from a text file?

Tags: python

I have a text file as following:

```
1, Max Mustermann, Male, 1000.0
2, Nora Mustermann, Female, 790.0
3, Tomas Mustermann, Male, 400.0
```

i want to read the last value from the fourth column if i type the persons number and the number 1 to show the value. Unfortunately, I can't get any further from here. How can i do this?

```
data_next = []
for data in open("my_data.txt"):
    liste = data.split(",")
    number = int(liste[0])
    name = liste[1]
    sex = liste[2]
    value = liste[3]
    data_next.append(number)
    print(f" [{number}] {name} {sex} {value}")


which_person = int(input("WHICH PERSON?: "))

if which_person in data_next:
    print("Do you want to know the value? Press 1 for YES or 2 for NO")
    next_input = int(input("YOUR INPUT: "))
    if next_input == 1:
        print(value)
    elif next_input == 2:
        print("THX")
```

Comment: What is the problem ? If I type `1` for each, it works, I see 400

Comment: Yes that is the problem. If I type 1 it should print out 1000.0 and not 400.0. What can I do?

Comment: See my answer, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop at the beginning of your code succeeds in placing all of the 'values' from the text file into one list.

```
data_next = ["1000.0", "790.0", "400.0"]
```

However, that list isn't useful for what you are trying to do below, which is to take input for one of the names from the data file and print the corresponding number. What you want for this is a dictionary, which links from one value to another. To achieve this, use the following code:

```
# set data_next to an empty dictionary
data_next = {}
for data in open("my_data.txt"):
    liste = data.split(",")
    number = int(liste[0])
    name = liste[1]
    sex = liste[2]
    value = liste[3]
    # set the current number equal to the current value in the dictionary
    data_next[number] = value
    print(f" [{number}] {name} {sex} {value}")


which_person = int(input("WHICH PERSON?: "))

# data_next.keys() will return an iterable of all of the id numbers in the dictionary
if which_person in data_next.keys():
    print("Do you want to know the value? Press 1 for YES or 2 for NO")
    next_input = int(input("YOUR INPUT: "))
    if next_input == 1:
        # data_next[which_person] will return the value in the dictionary assigned to the number which_person    
        print(data_next[which_person])
    elif next_input == 2:
        print("THX")
```

Another thing:
This code will perform slightly differently than you expect because of how the file is formatted When you split each line by ",".

```
"1, Max Mustermann, Male, 1000.0".split(",") == ["1", " Max Mustermann", " Male", " 1000.0"]
```

As you can see, the spaces after each comma are included with the next value. To fix this, change the split statement to split(", ") instead of split(",") OR remove the spaces after the commas in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the values as well in the structure, a `dict` is very well suited for that : number as key, values as value

```
data_next = {}
with open("my_data.txt") as fic:
    for data in fic:
        liste = data.split(",")
        number = int(liste[0])
        data_next[number] = liste[1:]
        print(f" [{number}] {liste[1:]}")
```

Then use the dict, to access the values

```
if which_person in data_next:
    print("Do you want to know the value? Press 1 for YES or 2 for NO")
    next_input = int(input("YOUR INPUT: "))
    if next_input == 1:
        print(data_next[which_person][2])
    elif next_input == 2:
        print("THX")
```

---

With regex you can handle nicely the comma+space delimiter

```
data_next = {}
with open("my_data.txt") as fic:
    for data in fic:
        nb, *others = re.fullmatch(r"(\d+),\s*([^,]+),\s*(\w+),\s*(\d+.?\d*)", data).groups()
        data_next[nb] = others
        print(f" [{nb}] {' '.join(others)}")
which_person = input("WHICH PERSON?: ")
```

Comment: Thx I've got it. But I Have a another question. I have implmented a `next_input == 3`. If this happens I can give a number and it will adds the current value. How can I save the changes in the same .txt file?

Comment: @virat open the file in "a" mode, and write on it. Google on how to append to a file in python

Answer (score 0):

maybe the easyst way is

```py
from csv import reader
from sys import exit
def get_person_row(number:int)->list or None:
    with open('my_data.txt','r') as file:
        table= reader(file)
        for row in table:
            if int(row[0]) == number:
                return row


try:
    which_person = int(input("WHICH PERSON?: "))
except ValueError:
    print('just numbers are valid for Id')
    exit(1)

line = get_person_row(which_person)
if line is None:
    print('invalid id')
else:
    print(str(line))
```